# Does Mac OS X store the names of DVDs that have been played?

Tags: macos, dvd, media-player, osx-tiger

I would like to see what DVDs have been played on my Mac OS X Tiger laptop.  Can you tell me how to view the file that contains this information?

Comment: Good question. There is a "Last Play" dictionary stored in  "~/Library/Application Support/DVD Player/Settings/Shared Settings.plist". There are also two corresponding files for each entry in the same directory. But I don't know how to decrypt/decode this information.

Answer (score 3):

The *DVD Player* app keeps some information about discs that it has played, but the storage is keyed by some sort of hash (the main part of each filename is a 16 hex digit number).

The info is stored in plist files under `~/Library/Application Support/DVD Player/Settings/`, but those bits of information might not be terribly useful. My collection of files represents 40 “unique” discs, but only two of them have a “MediaName” key that gives a meaningful name to the disc to which the data corresponds.

Here is a short shell script to extract any MediaName keys that exist:

```
for f in ~/'Library/Application Support/DVD Player/Settings'/*.plist; do
    medianame="$(defaults read "${f%.plist}" MediaName 2>/dev/null)" &&
      printf '%q is %s\n' "$f" "$medianame"
done
```

Or, if you are OK with assuming that the plist files are all in XML format:

```
grep -A 1 MediaName ~/'Library/Application Support/DVD Player/Settings'/*.plist
```

Comment: It appears Apple deliberately obfuscates this information, as on OS X 10.8.2 I see only *.enc (presumably meaning "encrypted") files instead of the individual plists for each media.  There's only the Shared Settings.plist that is readable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's quite recent, you could go to the Recent Items menu in the  menu.